# Close electron application using html button

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have a question,
i am making a electron application and i want to make it so that a user clicks a button thats in my index.html and that then the application closes.

i've tryed but nothing seems to work.. Annyone ideas?

Sorry for the bad English. im from Holland

- BeldrNL

Here's a image from the button in the html, it says 'close' in dutch. i want it so that a user presses that button the app closes
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuczo.png)

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried please

Comment: i have used this: app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  document.getElementById("exitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    app.quit()
  });
}) in main.js. And i have a button in my index.html with a id of exitBtn

Comment: Use `IPC` to send a message to `main` to call `app.quit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i've did it myself. I have added a window.close() on my button as so:

```
<button class="menu-btn" onclick="window.close()">Close</button>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not close the electron application, at least, not reliable. It just closes the current browser window